# How to open a recordset when the query should prompt for parameter values?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have an Access macro

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT WORKSTATION FROM [qry EngineHoursSummaryA]")
```

The line rs = db.OpenRecordset . . ., throws an error "Run-time error '3061': Too few parameters. Expected 2". It throws this error because [qry EngineHoursSummaryA] calls another query which has two parameters in it. When I run [qry EngineHoursSummaryA] in access normally, everything is fine, because Access displays two input boxes for me to put in the parameters.

But when I reference the query in my VBA macro, Access doesn't display those two input boxes. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To supply these parameters via VBA you need to use a `QuerfDef` and it's `Parameters` collection. You're query also needs to be a proper query and not an ad hoc query. I.e. you need to define `SELECT DISTINCT WORKSTATION FROM [qry EngineHoursSummaryA]` as it's own query. Then you can do this

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("YourQueryName")
qdef.Parameters.Refresh
qdef.Parameters("yourParameterName") = "value to Supply" 'No quotes if a number and #s if a date.
Set rs = qdef.OpenRecordset
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Don't have enough rep to vote up your answer or choose it. :(

Comment: @user2453293 you can always upvote and accept answers to your own questions. In fact accepting this should give you some rep